# Case-sensitive character replacement in a Swift string

Tags: swift, string

I need to replace characters in a Swift string case-sensitively.

I've been using the `replacingOccurrences(of:with:options:range:)` built-in string function to change every "a" to a "/a/", every "b" to a "/b/", and so on, like this:

```
stringConverted = stringConverted.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "/a/", options: [])
```

Then I change every "/a/" to its corresponding letter, which is "a". I change every "/b/" to its corresponding letter, which is "q", and so on.

My problem is that I need this replacement to be case-sensitive. I've looked this up, but I've tried what I found and it didn't help.

Do I need to use the `range` argument? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Replacement is already case-sensitive. You pass `options: [.caseInsensitive]` for case insensitive search.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @Orkhan mentioned you can pass `options: .caseInsensitive` like below

```
let a = "a"
let start = a.index(a.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
let end = a.index(a.startIndex, offsetBy: a.count)
let range = start..<end
let value = a.replacingOccurrences(of: "a", with: "/a", options: .caseInsensitive, range: range)
print(value)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this in a playground, and it worked, so it turns out that something else in my project was wrong, but at least I know I wasn't doing anything wrong